# Div bloqueado en el que no puedo acceder a un espacio

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No puedo usar la parte morada de este div y no sé cómo quitarlo y habilitar ese espacio.

El código:

```css
.container-fluid {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container container-fluid">
  <div class="col col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
    <div id="m2829" class="module map osmap osmap osmap osmap" data-url="?dm=m2829" data-req="mapbox-gl,leaflet,osmap" data-animate="">
      <div class="map-container" data-address="avinguda manel girona 31, castelldefels, barcelona, españa" data-zoom="10" data-mapstyle="bw">
        <div class="map-container" data-address="avinguda manel girona 31, castelldefels, barcelona, españa" data-zoom="10" data-mapstyle="bw">
          <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d139681.98961399126!2d1.940453592855058!3d41.271942148547346!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x12a482c9941ad3af%3A0xdd8466c2dde530bd!2sAvinguda%20de%20Manuel%20Girona%2C%2031%2C%2008860%20Castelldefels%2C%20Barcelona%2C%20Spagna!5e0!3m2!1ses!2ses!4v1699278013699!5m2!1ses!2ses"
            style="border:0;height: 100%;width: 100%;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="c3299" class="col col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
      <div id="m4214" class="module text">
        <p class="smalltext" style="font-weight: bold;">CONTACTA CON NOSOTROS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="module text">
        <p class="footertext">
          <span style="color: #282924;">
                                                <a style="color: #282924;" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=34635115088" target="_blank" rel="noopener" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="link_clicked">
                                                    <span class="iconfont "></span>
          </a>
          </span>
          <span class="iconfont "></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a data-global="phone" href="tel:635115088" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="phone_link">635 115 088</a>
        </p>
        <p class="footertext">
          <span class="iconfont "></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="mailto:carlosbifaz@gmail.com" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="email_link">info@dacarreformas.com</a>
        </p>
        <p class="footertext">
          <span class="iconfont "></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;Avinguda Manuel Girona, 31 - 35 2º Segunda,&nbsp;08860 &nbsp;Castelldefels,&nbsp;Barcelona
        </p>
      </div>
      <ul id="m4656" class="module iconlist">
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100054423163232" target="_blank" rel="noopener" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="link_clicked">
            <i class="iconItem fa fa-facebook-square "></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="HTTPS://www.instagram.com/dacar_reformas/">
            <i class="iconItem fa fa-instagram "></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="tel:635115088" target="_blank" rel="noopener" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="phone_link">
            <i class="iconItem fa fa-phone-square "></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="mailto:info@dacarreformas.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="email_link">
            <i class="iconItem fa fa-envelope-square "></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
      <div id="m1280" class="module text">
        <p class="smalltext">
          <span style="font-weight: bold;">ENLACES LEGALES</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="module text">
        <p class="footertext">
          <a href="/aviso-legal" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="internal_link_clicked">Aviso Legal</a>
        </p>
        <p class="footertext">
          <a href="/politica-de-privacidad" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="internal_link_clicked">Política de Privacidad</a>
        </p>
        <p class="footertext">
          <a href="/politica-de-cookies" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="internal_link_clicked">Política de Cookies</a>
          <a href="/politica-de-cookies" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="internal_link_clicked"></a>
          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
      <a id="m4925" class="module button2" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=34635115088" target="_blank" rel="noopener" title="" data-fixedposition="bottom-right" role="button" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="link_clicked">
        <i class="buttonIcon fa fa-whatsapp"></i>
        <span class="buttonLabel labelRight"></span>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

La verdad no sé por qué se pone así en el navegador. Ya le quité la mayoría de los estilos que tenia a ver si era eso y no, todavía sigue dándome ese problema.

Elimine la clasé *container* e igual da esa ampliación.

Y le quité las clases a todos los `div` que contiene el container, pero sigue dando ese mismo problema.

Comment: ¿Podrías editar la pregunta para añadir el HTML y así poder replicar el problema? El CSS es solamente la mitad del contexto, para temas de estilos es necesario también el HTML.

Comment: Listo ya agregue el html y mas informacion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te está ocurriendo porque estás usando erróneamente las cajas flexibles (`display: flex)`. Las cajas flexibles, cuando son `flex-direction: row`, van a tener un ancho variable, adaptándose al ancho que le impongan los elementos a los que contiene.

Si necesitas que el ancho sea del 100% puedes usar `flex-direction: column`:

```css
.container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-fluid">
  <div class="col col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
      <div id="m2829" class="module map osmap osmap osmap osmap" data-url="?dm=m2829" data-req="mapbox-gl,leaflet,osmap" data-animate="">
          <div class="map-container" data-address="avinguda manel girona 31, castelldefels, barcelona, españa" data-zoom="10" data-mapstyle="bw">
              <div class="map-container" data-address="avinguda manel girona 31, castelldefels, barcelona, españa" data-zoom="10" data-mapstyle="bw">
                  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d139681.98961399126!2d1.940453592855058!3d41.271942148547346!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x12a482c9941ad3af%3A0xdd8466c2dde530bd!2sAvinguda%20de%20Manuel%20Girona%2C%2031%2C%2008860%20Castelldefels%2C%20Barcelona%2C%20Spagna!5e0!3m2!1ses!2ses!4v1699278013699!5m2!1ses!2ses" style="border:0;height: 100%;width: 100%;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="c3299" class="col col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
      <div id="m4214" class="module text">
          <p class="smalltext" style="font-weight: bold;">CONTACTA CON NOSOTROS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="module text">
          <p class="footertext">
              <span style="color: #282924;">
                  <a style="color: #282924;" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=34635115088" target="_blank" rel="noopener" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="link_clicked">
                      <span class="iconfont "></span>
                  </a>
              </span>
              <span class="iconfont "></span>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;<a data-global="phone" href="tel:635115088" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="phone_link">635 115 088</a>
          </p>
          <p class="footertext">
              <span class="iconfont "></span>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:carlosbifaz@gmail.com" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="email_link">info@dacarreformas.com</a>
          </p>
          <p class="footertext">
              <span class="iconfont "></span>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;Avinguda Manuel Girona, 31 - 35 2º Segunda,&nbsp;08860 &nbsp;Castelldefels,&nbsp;Barcelona
          </p>
      </div>
      <ul id="m4656" class="module iconlist">
          <li>
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100054423163232" target="_blank" rel="noopener" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="link_clicked">
                  <i class="iconItem fa fa-facebook-square "></i>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="HTTPS://www.instagram.com/dacar_reformas/">
                  <i class="iconItem fa fa-instagram "></i>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="tel:635115088" target="_blank" rel="noopener" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="phone_link">
                  <i class="iconItem fa fa-phone-square "></i>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="mailto:info@dacarreformas.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="email_link">
                  <i class="iconItem fa fa-envelope-square "></i>
              </a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
      <div id="m1280" class="module text">
          <p class="smalltext">
              <span style="font-weight: bold;">ENLACES LEGALES</span>
          </p>
      </div>
      <div class="module text">
          <p class="footertext">
              <a href="/aviso-legal" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="internal_link_clicked">Aviso Legal</a>
          </p>
          <p class="footertext">
              <a href="/politica-de-privacidad" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="internal_link_clicked">Política de Privacidad</a>
          </p>
          <p class="footertext">
              <a href="/politica-de-cookies" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="internal_link_clicked">Política de Cookies</a>
              <a href="/politica-de-cookies" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="internal_link_clicked"></a>
              <br>
          </p>
      </div>
      <a id="m4925" class="module button2" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=34635115088" target="_blank" rel="noopener" title="" data-fixedposition="bottom-right" role="button" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="link_clicked">
          <i class="buttonIcon fa fa-whatsapp"></i>
          <span class="buttonLabel labelRight"></span>
      </a>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Por otro lado, parece que estás usando Bootstrap. El comportamiento que estás tratando de forzar con tu CSS es el comportamiento por defecto de las clases de Bootstrap que estás utilizando, por lo que yo no lo pisaría.

También veo que no estás usando bien Bootstrap, ya que estás usando un `.col` que no es hijo directo de un `.row`, lo que te provocaría comportamientos indeseados. Adjunto tu código adaptado para como creo que debería ser usado con Bootstrap.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
            <div id="m2829" class="module map osmap osmap osmap osmap" data-url="?dm=m2829" data-req="mapbox-gl,leaflet,osmap" data-animate="">
                <div class="map-container" data-address="avinguda manel girona 31, castelldefels, barcelona, españa" data-zoom="10" data-mapstyle="bw">
                    <div class="map-container" data-address="avinguda manel girona 31, castelldefels, barcelona, españa" data-zoom="10" data-mapstyle="bw">
                        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d139681.98961399126!2d1.940453592855058!3d41.271942148547346!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x12a482c9941ad3af%3A0xdd8466c2dde530bd!2sAvinguda%20de%20Manuel%20Girona%2C%2031%2C%2008860%20Castelldefels%2C%20Barcelona%2C%20Spagna!5e0!3m2!1ses!2ses!4v1699278013699!5m2!1ses!2ses" style="border:0;height: 100%;width: 100%;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
            <div id="m1280" class="module text">
                <p class="smalltext">
                    <span style="font-weight: bold;">ENLACES LEGALES</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="module text">
                <p class="footertext">
                    <a href="/aviso-legal" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="internal_link_clicked">Aviso Legal</a>
                </p>
                <p class="footertext">
                    <a href="/politica-de-privacidad" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="internal_link_clicked">Política de Privacidad</a>
                </p>
                <p class="footertext">
                    <a href="/politica-de-cookies" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="internal_link_clicked">Política de Cookies</a>
                    <a href="/politica-de-cookies" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="internal_link_clicked"></a>
                    <br>
                </p>
            </div>
            <a id="m4925" class="module button2" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=34635115088" target="_blank" rel="noopener" title="" data-fixedposition="bottom-right" role="button" data-track-event="click" data-track-action="link_clicked">
                <i class="buttonIcon fa fa-whatsapp"></i>
                <span class="buttonLabel labelRight"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

En este segundo ejemplo he cargado Bootstrap y si te fijas no uso CSS adicional al que usa Bootstrap a través de sus clases.